# convert data matrix using awk

Tags: matrix, awk, transpose

Is it possible to transpose the following data matrix input to the desired output?

```
f1  x1  1.2
f1  x2  2.2
f1  x3  0
f2  x1  1.1 
f2  x2  1.2
f2  x3  3.3
f3  x1  2.3
f3  x2  4.4
f3  x3  0.1
```

output

```
    f1  f2  f3
x1  1.2 1.1 2.3
x2  2.2 1.2 4.4
x3  0   3.3 0.1
```

Comment: Please see duplicate question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7906095/from-xyz-to-matrix-with-awk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be a way:

```
awk '{a[$1,$2]=$3; col[$1]; row[$2]}
    END {printf "%s", FS
            for (c in col) printf "%s%s", c, FS; print "";
            for (r in row) { 
                printf "%s%s", r, FS
                for (c in col) printf "%s%s", a[c,r], FS
                print ""
            }
        }' file
```

It is quite descriptive, but still:

- Store the data in an array `a[col, row]`.
- Store the possible names of cols and rows.

Once the file has been read, loop through the results and print.

For the given input it returns:

```
$ awk '{a[$1,$2]=$3; col[$1]; row[$2]} END {printf "%s", FS; for (c in col) printf "%s%s", c, FS; print ""; for (r in row) { printf "%s%s", r, FS; for (c in col) printf "%s%s", a[c,r], FS; print ""}}' a
f1 f2 f3 
x1 1.2 1.1 2.3 
x2 2.2 1.2 4.4 
x3 0 3.3 0.1
```

Comment: Yes, I know there is no approach at all by the OP, but felt like doing it :|

Answer (score 0):

```
% cat mat.rix 
f1  x1  1.2
f1  x2  2.2
f1  x3  0
f2  x1  1.1 
f2  x2  1.2
f2  x3  3.3
f3  x1  2.3
f3  x2  4.4
f3  x3  0.1
% cat a.wk
{
  if(! row[$1]) { i=i+1; rowname[i]=$1; row[$1]=1 }
  if(! col[$2]) { j=j+1; colname[j]=$2; col[$2]=1 }
  if(c[$2])
     c[$2] = sprintf("%s%s%10.4f", c[$2], OFS, $3)
  else
     c[$2] = sprintf("%10.4f", $3)
}
END {
  printf "   "
  for(n=1;n<i+1;n++){ printf "%10s%s", rowname[n], OFS } ; print ""
  for(n=1;n<j+1;n++){ print colname[n], c[colname[n]] }}
% awk -f a.wk mat.rix 
           f1         f2         f3 
x1     1.2000     1.1000     2.3000
x2     2.2000     1.2000     4.4000
x3     0.0000     3.3000     0.1000
%
```

---

### *Addendum*

What if the column names are of different length?

```
% cat aw.k
{
  if(! row[$1]) { i=i+1; rowname[i]=$1; row[$1]=1 }
  if(! col[$2]) { j=j+1; colname[j]=$2; col[$2]=1 }
  if(c[$2])
     c[$2] = sprintf("%s%s%10.4f", c[$2], OFS, $3)
  else
     c[$2] = sprintf("%10.4f", $3)
}
END {
  for(n=1;n<j+1;n++){l = length(colname[n]) ; if(l>lmax) lmax=l}
  format = sprintf("%%-%ds%%s%%s\n", lmax)
  for(n=1;n<lmax+1;n++) printf "."; printf OFS
  for(n=1;n<i+1;n++){ printf "%10s%s", rowname[n], OFS } ; print ""
  for(n=1;n<j+1;n++){ printf(format, colname[n], OFS, c[colname[n]])}
}
% awk -f aw.k mat.rix 
..         f1         f2         f3 
x1     1.2000     1.1000     2.3000
x2     2.2000     1.2000     4.4000
x3     0.0000     3.3000     0.1000
%
```

please consider the use of `%%` when the `format` is built using `sprintf`